# How to remove namespace value from inside lxml.html.html5paser element tag

Tags: python, html, lxml, html5lib

Is it possible not to add namespace for the tag when using 
html5parser from the lxml.html package?

Example:

```
from lxml import html
print(html.parse('http://example.com').getroot().tag)
# You will get 'html'

from lxml.html import html5parser
print(html5parser.parse('http://example.com').getroot().tag)
# You will get '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html'
```

The easiest solution I found is to remove that using regex, but 
maybe it's possible not to include that text at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific `namespaceHTMLElements` boolean flag that controls this behavior:

```
from lxml.html import html5parser
from html5lib import HTMLParser

root = html5parser.parse('http://example.com', 
                         parser=HTMLParser(namespaceHTMLElements=False))    
print(root.tag)  # prints "html"
```

Comment: In principle this should work for lxml's API too AIUI, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731479/lxml-html5parser-ignores-namespacehtmlelements-false-option) about that.