# Why doesn't cssselect work with html5parser?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to use `cssselect` on some HTML page parsed by `lxml`, but I found that only one parser gives the expected result:

This works just fine:

```
lxml.html.fromstring("...").cssselect("div.foo")
```

This returns no results:

```
lxml.html.html5parser.fromstring("...").cssselect("div.foo")
```

What's the difference? And can I get cssselect to work with `html5parser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see these two answers about the reason:

[How to remove namespace value from inside lxml.html.html5paser element tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012693/how-to-remove-namespace-value-from-inside-lxml-html-html5paser-element-tag)

[lxml html5parser ignores "namespaceHTMLElements=False" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731479/lxml-html5parser-ignores-namespacehtmlelements-false-option)

In short, the reason is that the parse from `html5lib` adds namespace `html` to the element tree while other parsers don't.

I think it should be a bug, from `lxml` side, maybe... To fix this:

```
import lxml.html.html5parser
from html5lib import HTMLParser
from html5lib.treebuilders.etree_lxml import TreeBuilder

parser = HTMLParser(tree=TreeBuilder, namespaceHTMLElements=False)
print(lxml.html.html5parser.fromstring("<div class=\"foo\"></div>", parser=parser))
```